# Matrix transformation verification

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

I have a very simple question about matrix transformations here. I did the question but I just need a verification to see if my work is right. Also, is there a way I could check my answer?

[image: Question and work]

Comment: Everything seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers look good to me.

As for where you can check your answers, there is no software anywhere that could just "check your answer" in general. You can check that the multiplication of the vector by the matrix is correct using any software that can manipulate matrices, but to answer a general mathematical question... well... if you write that software, you will be a rich man.

Comment: Haha I figured that much out. I guess I was really asking is there an intuitive way to reason out that this is a reasonable answer.